# Zero-Knowledge Proof of a polynomial

Tags: protocol-design, zero-knowledge-proofs

I have two secret values $L_1$, $L_2$, and two Pedersen commitments $C_1 = C(L_1)$, $C_2=C(L_2)$. The commitments $C_1$, $C_2$ are public. Given a challenge $c$, I want to output $d = c*L_1+L_2$ and prove in zero-knowledge that $d$ is formed correctly. What should the zero-knowledge proof look like?

Comment: What do the commitments look like? ​ ​

Comment: Pedersen Commitment: C(x) = g^xh^r

Comment: @Hongyang The value $c$ is secret?

Comment: Challenge is something sent by Verifier to Prover while interactive proof, so $c$ probably is something else.

Comment: @DrLecter the challenge c is generated by the verifier and is public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a multiplicative group of an order $q$ generated by some $g$. For simplicity, let commitment be $C_1 = g^{L_1}$. Consider a proof of knowledge of $L_1$ committed to at $C_1$. At the first step of an interactive proof, choose some $L_2$ at random and send $C_2 = g^{L_2}$ to the verifying party. Second step, receive a challenge $c$. Third step, send a response $d = c L_1 + L_2 \pmod{q}$. Now verify this response with $g^d=$ something computable by the verifying party. That is, an expression of something that was sent to verifying party before or while running the protocol.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. One question: does this simultaneously prove that the prover knows the value $L_1$ and $L_2$ committed in $C_1$ and $C_2$ respectively?

Comment: This explanation is not complete yet. Did you get verification equation? Did you read Schnorr protocol?  To be a proof of knowledge, such a protocol must admit an extractor algorithm that would output the value committed.

Comment: The verifier is given $d$, $C_1 = g^{L_1}$ and $C_2 = g^{L_2}$, and verifies that $g^d = (C_1)^cC_2$, right?

Comment: Right. Please note it is essential that Prover is given challenge $c$ only after he sends his first protocol message, commitment $C_2$. Next, to be zero knowledge, a proof must admit simulator algorithm that would output simulated transcript.

Comment: I'm not sure I get the point about the simulated transcript. Why is the current proof incomplete? Could you elaborate a little bit? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: It would be complete with verification equation, simulator and extractor algorithms. Did you read anything on that two algorithms? Simulated transcript should be indistinguishable from transcript of protocol with real Prover.

Comment: I googled around a bit. If I understand correctly, the simulator algorithm makes sure that whatever the verifier learns from the interaction with the prover, the verifier can also learn it from a simulator algorithm without interacting with the prover, and thus the proof itself is zero-knowledge. The extractor algorithm makes sure that the prover actually knows the secret value in the commitment.

Comment: What I'm a bit confused about is this: are the extractor algorithm and the simulator algorithm part of the protocol, in the sense that the prover and the verifier have to interact with each other and run these algorithms, or are they just ways that we reason about the actual interaction between the prover and the verifier?

Comment: In other words, is it true that the actual protocol, after the verifier verifies the equation $g^d = (C_1)^cC_2$, is complete (in the sense that the prover and the verifier don't have to do any computations), and the extractor and the simulator algorithm are just what we need to theoretically argue that the actual protocol is zero-knowledge proof-of-knowledge?

Comment: Yes, the protocol itself is complete with verification equation; extractor and simulator are about properties of the protocol. Prover and Verifier do not interact while running that algorithms; Verifier is running simulator alone and Prover is responding to another Turing machine that is running extractor.

Comment: Thanks! I have another follow-up question: if $L_1$ and $L_2$ are committed in the generalized Pedersen commitment $C = g_1^{L_1}g_2^{L_2}h^r$, where $r$ opens the commitment, can the protocol be modified somehow so that the prover proves that $d = cL_1 + L_2$ is revealed correctly? I mean we don't have a common generator $g$ that allows us to do the $g^d$ trick anymore.

Comment: For commitment scheme made of 3 group elements and 3 secrets $(L_1, L_2, r)$, there will be 3 responses in place of the single $d$. Proving a relation about secrets (like a linear combination in the original question) would take another verification equation for that responses.

Comment: Oh I think I get it now. Let's say $C = g_1^{L_1}g_2^{L_2}$. To show that the prover knows the committed secret, the prover generates random $t_1, t_2$ and sends over $T = g_1^{t_1}g_2^{t_2}$. The verifier responds with a challenge $c$, and the prover sends back $s_1 = cL_1+t_1, s_2=cL_2+t_2$. Finally the verifier verifies that $g_1^{s_1}g_2^{s_2} = C^cT$.

Comment: Then, to prove that $d$ is revealed correctly, i.e., $d = cL_1+L_2$, the prover in addition constructs $T' = g_1^{t_1-L_2}g_2^{t_2-c^2L_1}$, and the verifier checks that $g_1^{s_1}g_2^{s_2} = g_1^dg_2^{dc}T'$. Is this correct?

Comment: Right, with two responses $(s_1, s_2)$ Prover would convince Verifier that he knows two secrets that would open commitment $C$. For this particular $T'$, Prover could only calculate it after receiving challenge $c$. Besides, relation $c L_1 + L_2$ depends on the challenge so it is unknown before running the protocol. Let me guess it: would it be practical to open a linear combination of secrets for some known $e$, like $d = e L_1 + L_2$. To do it, consider verification equation for $e s_1 + s_2$ and an additional message to be sent at step 1 (like $T$).